# VB.NET WebBrowser Control Click Event

Tags: vb.net, click, browser

The webbrowser control doesn't have a lot of the events like the rest of the controls.

For instance, there's no MouseMove or Click events in the WebBrowser control.

How would one go about registering a Click or an interaction with the WebBrowser control?

Comment: The events occur inside of the browser itself.  Typically handled by Javascript.  They are available externally: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement_events.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mouse and keyboard events can be handled from the Document Body of the WebBrowser control.
take a look at this post, it was very useful for me, hope it will help you too

http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/easy-way-to-add-keyboard-and-mouse-events-to-webbrowser-control/

Regards,